# tense-agreement

Tags: tense-agreement

> Sarah says she wants me to get a job, as she says we need the money. I
>   **said** she **has** a great job that pays relly well. We can live comfortably
>   without me getting a job.

---

Is there any problem in the article about Grammar? The main clause's tense of the second sentence is the past one "said" but the subordinate clause's one is the present one "has". I think they are not in the proper use. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming that she still has the same job.

The verb to say is in the past tense because it refers to a past event -you telling her about her job.

The verb to have is in the present tense because it refers to a state of affairs that was current at that time and which is still current -her having a great job.

```
I said she has a great job.
```

If she no longer has the same job then you would use the past tense with the verb to have because you are referring to a state of affairs which is no longer current.

```
I said she had a great job.
```

If you don't know about her current job status you can use either depending on the likelihood of her still having the same job.